# How to set maxrequests in Django when using fastcgi with method=threaded to release memory leaks?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a Django server which handle ajax requests using django-rest-framework. I noticed for every 100 ajax requests, my django process consume about 1MG of memory, so every week I have to kill the process and recreate it manually to avoid crashing.

In this post "[deploying-django-site-using-fastcgi](https://github.com/djangoadvent/djangoadvent-articles/blob/master/1.2/10_deploying-django-site-using-fastcgi.rst#choosing-options-for-our-fastcgi-server)" I see there is a maxrequests parameter to force Django process recreation automatically after handling #maxrequests of requests. unfortunately this parameter only works in `method=prefork` not in `method=threaded`. `method=prefork` use multiple process and more memory than `method=threaded` so I don't want to use it.

My question: is there any way to set maxrequests or something similar in `method=threaded` and what is the best way to avoid memory leaks in Django?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using fcgi instead of something like mod_wsgi or uwsgi?

Comment: @JoshSmeaton No. I'm using nginx and I could found only fcgi configuration for Django+Nginx. are mod_wsgi or uwsgi more efficient in memory consumption?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I've got configuration files for uwsgi/emperor on github. https://github.com/jarshwah/django-project-skel/tree/master/project_name/wsgi/uwsgi and https://github.com/jarshwah/django-project-skel/tree/master/config

Comment: Are mod_wsgi or uwsgi known to be more efficient in memory consumption? anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I would avoid mod_wsgi (apache is heavy). The standard for deploying django seems to be using uwsgi (or gunicorn), but I don't know the benefits over fast cgi. uwsgi lets you control the number of processes and threads, and includes a max-requests option for process recycling.